# Comparing datetime 24hs to AM/PM format with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime-format

I am new with Entity Framework. I am having problems comparing datetime values since in my SQL Server database the datetime values are stored as 24hs format and the application is taking the time format as A.M./P.M. format. I tried to parse the fields but I get the error message:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.>

Here is what I tried: (this returns true or false if there are any record found)

```
<pre><code>
     return !(DB.Eventos.Where(
                x =>
                (x.Fecha_inicio_evento.Date >= eventos.Fecha_inicio_evento.Date
                &&
                x.Fecha_inicio_evento.TimeOfDay >= eventos.Fecha_inicio_evento.TimeOfDay
                &&
                x.Fecha_inicio_evento.Date <= eventos.Fecha_fin_evento.Date
                &&
                x.Fecha_inicio_evento.TimeOfDay <= eventos.Fecha_fin_evento.TimeOfDay)
                ||
                (x.Fecha_fin_evento.Date >= eventos.Fecha_inicio_evento.Date
                &&
                x.Fecha_fin_evento.TimeOfDay >= eventos.Fecha_fin_evento.TimeOfDay
                &&
                x.Fecha_fin_evento.Date <= eventos.Fecha_fin_evento.Date
                &&
                x.Fecha_fin_evento.TimeOfDay <= eventos.Fecha_fin_evento.TimeOfDay
                )).Any());
</code></pre>
```

Do you know any way to perform that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Database` or `.Net` does not store date in format. Format is only description for methods like `ToString` how to do the task. So comparison can be done standard way with operator. Error you're getting is connected with translation `Linq` query to `sql` by `entity framework`, simply `Date` isn't upported.

If by splitting comparison to 2 parts you wanted to compare the dates its not correct. Id `.Date` is higher comparison of the `.TimeofDay` shouldn't change result but it does. Chech result with  `Fecha_inicio_evento` = 2011-01-02 01:01:01 and `Fecha_inicio_evento` = 2011-01-01 02:01:01